# ERROR: [Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry] ['MODULE_NOT_FOUND'] [Request : 'readable-stream']

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-package

I have an error when I use any npm command
It says like this:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.20.2\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js:31
    throw err
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.20.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\readable.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:438:19)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:680:18)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1063:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.20.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\lib\tracker-stream.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v16.20.2\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\readable-stream\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'readable-stream'
}

Node.js v18.18.0
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.20.2\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js:31
    throw err
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.20.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\readable.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:438:19)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:680:18)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1063:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.20.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\lib\tracker-stream.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v16.20.2\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\readable-stream\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'readable-stream'
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Probably start by showing the [mcve] that reproduces this for you. Right now there's simply [not enough information](/help/how-to-ask) for anyone to actually know what's wrong.